# trying to connect expo app to bluestacks error No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm working on a react native app with expo and i'm trying to use bluestacks as an android emulator, i have the bluestacks open and running and on my command line (git bash) i use

```
expo start --android
```

but i get the following error:

```
could not connect to TCP port 5554: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5554: No connection 
could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
[14:28:35] Error: adb exited with non-zero code: 1
```

what could be causing this and how can i fix it?